# fs module does not rename a file

Tags: javascript, node.js, fs

I have a function called `normalize_string()` that removes Brazilian characters from any string.

I need to remove all Brazilian characters from files and directories from a root directory that has several subdirectories and files.

I'm using the `recursive-readdir` package to list files recursively. Within `recursive`, when I try to use the Node.js `fs.rename()` method, the following error appears:

```
[Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, rename '/home/caleb/Documents/test_rename/fólder/águia.txt' -> '/home/caleb/Documents/test_rename/folder/aguia.txt'] {
  errno: -2,
  code: 'ENOENT',
  syscall: 'rename',
  path: '/home/caleb/Documents/test_rename/fólder/águia.txt',
  dest: '/home/caleb/Documents/test_rename/folder/aguia.txt'
}
```

The main code currently looks like this:

```js
const fs = require("fs")
const recursive = require("recursive-readdir");

const normalize_string = require("./normalize-string.js")

recursive("/home/caleb/Documents/test_rename", function (err, files) {
  for (const file of files) {
    const normalized = normalize_string(file)
    fs.rename(file, normalized, (error) => {
      console.error(error)
    })
  }
});
```

And the function to normalize a string is as follows:

```js
module.exports = function normalize_string(str) {
  const removed_symbols = str.replace(/[!*\[\]{};:$@~`´,#%^&+=<>]/g, '')
  const normalized_string = removed_symbols.normalize("NFD").replace(/[\u0300-\u036f]/g, "")
  return normalized_string
}
```

It seems to me that the correct paths and the function of normalizing a string are being used as well, but this error intrigued me.

Any help is welcome. Thank you.

Comment: You're removing the accents from the directory name, not just the filename. But you never renamed the directory to not have accents.

Comment: `recursive-readdir` only returns files, not directories.

Comment: And `fs.rename` won't create the missing directory.